# Creating other page than page.php

Tags: menus

I want to load other page than page.php. I mean following situation:
Always when I click position from menu it is starting page.php. I want to special position in menu sutch that it load my.php (which will be similar to page.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress allows you to create [custom page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). Create your own template and assign that template to any page you like in the WordPress admin ;)

Comment: The url changed to https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/